# combination of \dontrun and \donttest?

Tags: r, package

I have bits of code that I want to show in the examples of a package but *neither run* (when `example(my_fun)` is run) *nor test* (when `R CMD check` is run) because they're slow enough to annoy users who might unthinkingly run them, and definitely slow enough to annoy the CRAN maintainers.

[Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions) says

> You can use `\dontrun{}` for text that should only be shown, but not run ...

and

> Finally, there is `\donttest`, used (at the beginning of a separate line) to mark code that should be run by `example()` but not by `R CMD check`.

Should I nest these, i.e.

```
\donttest
\dontrun{first slow example ...}
\dontrun{second slow example ...}
```

?  That technically seems to go against the wording in WRE (i.e. it says that `\donttest` code *should* be run by `example()` ...) ?

I could just include them in the examples in a commented-out form or using `if (FALSE) { ... }` if it came to it ... but that seems ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\dontrun` subsumes `\donttest`: code that is marked with the former will neither be run by `example()`, nor by `R CMD check`. I know this because my packages for talking to Azure use `\dontrun` liberally, for examples that assume you have an Azure account.

Comment: thanks! I don't know if WRE is unclear or I'm obtuse but I spent quite a while poring over those bits of text ...